# Hash ordered in the way it was created

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-1.8

I need a hash key-value pairs to be in the same order as I have assigned. Created Hash in Ruby 1.8:

```
tmp = {}
tmp["name"] = "laxman"
tmp["age"] = "25"
tmp["city"] = "pune"
tmp # => {"city"=>"pune", "name"=>"laxman", "age"=>"25"}
```

I need the output:

```
tmp # => {"name"=>"laxman", "age"=>"25","city"=>"pune"}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Just tested and I am getting {"name"=>"laxman", "age"=>"25", "city"=>"pune"}

Comment: I also just tested it. It displays in the order they are created.

Comment: @all, I forgot to mention, I am trying with ruby 1.8.7. I have updated output in question.

Comment: Don't even try to use 1.8.7. It's old, unmaintained and very inefficient. Use at least a Ruby 2.x version.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti, I understand but I am working on old maintenance project.

Comment: @LaxmanMore I supposed it and in fact I provided you an answer. But please note your project is at serious security risk. Your highest priority before any feature or change should be to upgrade it. Seriously.

Comment: Do not rely on hash ordering. Instead, sort the keys the way you want and then extract the values using the ordered keys. That works no matter what version of Ruby your code is running on. I never care what order the hash is in, only what order my keys are in.

Comment: @theTinMan, we are working on client requirement, for my client order is important, so my job is to give what order he want. Coming to sorting, then I don't want sorting on ascending or descending. I need same order how I have explained in my question. Please advise for that. Thanks In advance.

Comment: The client specified the hash has to be sorted? Or did they require the hash had values or keys that had to be retrieved in a certain order? There is a big difference. How code is implemented is up to the developer. What it returns is where the customer's request gets met.

Comment: Show us what you have written toward solving this. As is, it looks like you are fishing for solutions hoping we will solve it for you, instead of us helping debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Ruby 1.9 the `Hash` preserves the order of the keys.

However, if you are using an older version or if for whatever reason the behavior doesn't satisfy you, it's fairly easy to create a custom `OrderedHash` type that relies on an `Array` to keep the order of the keys and on a `Hash` as a storage.

`ActiveSupport` was used to provide an implementation back in the days where it supported Ruby < 2.0. [You can find it here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.22/activesupport/lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb).

Comment: Ruby actually does that since 1.9: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_0_0/doc/NEWS#L145

Comment: The second paragraph is the key to creating a sorted hash. An array of keys sorted in the desired order, and a loop and `map`, or using `values_at` to retrieve the values.